# Convertir objeto tipo Buffer a string en javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Tengo un objeto, que forma parte de un json que traigo de la base de datos, con esta estructura:

```
data:[83,78,77,80,32,65,103,101,110,116,32,52,65,32,32,32,86,101,114,115,105,111,110,32,110,97,109,101,32,48,46,50,46,53,32,40,50,53,41] (39)
type: "Buffer"
```

Quisiera saber como convertirlo a una cadena de texto (decodificando los caracteres), he intentado con `toString('utf8')` pero sigue imprimiendo `[object Object]`, existe algún otro modo de realizarlo?

El valor resultante tiene que ser `SNMP Agent 4A   Version name 0.2.5 (25)--SysDescr`.

pdta: la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando es postgresql y una columna de la tabla que utilizo guarda json.

Comment: El tipo de data que estás trayendo es un objeto de tipo `Buffer`, que supongo ha de venir desde un entorno de programación en Node.js. Si es así no puedes operar métodos de esa clase en el frontend, tienes que convertir esos datos antes en tu backend.

Comment: Perdon pero tu pregunta no especifica donde viene ese dato esperado similar `SNMP Agent 4A   Version name 0.2.5 (25)--SysDescr`, si viene en una cabecera o es parte de los atributos resultantes devueltos, Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia o supone que todos sabemos el formato de dicho buffer, se mas explicito con la información que estas proporcionando no podemos leer tu mente.

Answer (score 1):

para convertirlo a string, siempre que no tenga métodos puedes usar [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) a fin de cuenta los objetos en javascript no son mas que array asociativos de tipo clave valor, donde un valor puede ser una funcion en si mismo.

```js
let data = {
  data: [83, 78, 77, 80, 32, 65, 103, 101, 110, 116],
  type: "Buffer"
};

$("#resultado").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Comment: El resultado que quiero obtener es un texto, no los números, existe algún modo de "decodificar" ese objeto buffer? (acabo de agregar todos los elementos y el resultado que deberían dar)

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal, lo que necesitas es transformar los números a caracteres:

```js
let array = [83, 78, 77, 80, 32, 65, 103, 101, 110, 116, 32, 52, 65, 32,
    32, 32, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101,
    32, 48, 46, 50 ,46 ,53 ,32 ,40 ,50 ,53 ,41 ];


console.log(String.fromCharCode(...array))
```

EDIT: Efectivamente, el array de números, al interpretarlos como códigos de caracteres, da el resultado que buscas: `SNMP Agent 4A   Version name 0.2.5 (25)`